# How to ask about time: ____ are you open?

Tags: questions

This is a dialogue between two persons in a museum,

> A: Is it the Egyptian museum?
>   B: Yes,It is the Egyptian museum.
>   A: ........are you open?
>   B: we are open at 5:00 O'CLOCK

my question is to complete the missing words by asking about time, which is the correct answer? what you open? or when are you open?complete the dialogue by the correct word to ask about time grammatically.

Answer (score 1):

If I worked the phone lines at the Egyptian museum, and someone asked me:

> *When are you open?*

or:

> *What time are you open?*

Then I would give them the full range of the hours the museum is open:

> We are open from 9 to 5.

However, if they asked me instead:

> *What time **do** you open?* (or "When do you open?")

Then I would give them the time the museum opens:

> We open at 9 AM.

---

I'm guessing that 5 o'clock is when the museum closes, not when it opens. So, I'd expect that dialog to go something like this:

> *What time are you open **until**?*

or:

> *When do you **close**?*

In which case I'd say:

> We **close** at 5 o'clock.

---

The answer:

> We are open at 5 o'clock.

tells me that's the time when the museum opens its doors. Five in the morning seems like a good time for a breakfast diner to open, and 5PM might be a good opening time for a nightclub, but it's hard to imagine a museum opening at five o'clock.

However, had your question read:

> We are open **until** 5 o'clock.

that would make more sense.

Comment: +1 You might want to add that *What time are you open* uses the adjective *open*, but *What time do you open* uses the verb *open*. (Just because a lot of lower level students say things like **Where are you work?* - so they might otherwise get the impression that *When are you open* has a verb *open* an the main verb.)